# Make a element move

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Im creating mini game. I have a circle that is moving on background. But I need when I tap for exemple right, circle should place another circles behind, I mean if circle is for exemple `x`, it should make circles `x - 1` if I tap again `x - 2`.

```
for (int i = Snake.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Right))
    {
        Settings.direction = Direction.Right;
        Snake[i].X++;
    }
    else if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Left))
    {
        Settings.direction = Direction.Left;
        Snake[i].X--;
    }
    else if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Up))
    {
        Settings.direction = Direction.Up;
        Snake[i].Y--;
    }
    else if (Input.KeyPressed(Keys.Down))
    {
        Settings.direction = Direction.Down;
        Snake[i].Y++;
    }
}
PaintBox1.Invalidate();
//snake is a list of circles
```

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
__Always__ tag your question correctly!

Comment: are you porting qbasic nibbles? they used ascii art for graphics, but the principle of storing the snake segments in an array and keeping track of their length so the tail could be erased as they move, would apply here. One Queue<Point> per snake could do.